# Global mouseListener in java for linux

Tags: java, c++, linux

Hi there I'm making a program about linux control and I need to read mouse location and events outside my app window.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `java.awt.MouseInfo` class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html

Comment: thanks,But that only helps me to know the mouse's location.Also when the mouse button is clicked or the scroll was used I need to know when,where and which button was clicked... etc

Comment: @DarkJustice: You're likely better off not trying to do this with Java.  If this is to be done on Windows, consider using a Windows scripting language such as AutoIt.

Comment: Isn't there a possible way using (jni and c++) or (shell scripting).